# RSA from Android to PHP

Tags: php, android, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I've been searching all day long(aprox. 12 hours) how to deal with this and couldn't find anything to work for me so I decided to make another question on the topic.

My setup:

1. Taking credentials from user
2. Encrypt them using RSA public key and then base64
3. Send to server
4. base64_decode, decrypt and check credentials

This is the code I use for encryption on Android:

```
    public class Encrypter {
        public static PublicKey loadPublicKey(Context context) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("public_key.txt");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(bytes);

            PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance(RSA).generatePublic(
                    new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(bytes)));

      return publicKey;
    }

    private static byte[] enc(String text, PublicKey pubRSA) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubRSA);
        return cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    public final static String encrypt(String text, PublicKey uk) {
        try {
            return Base64.encodeBytes(enc(text, uk));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And how I use it:

```
 String username = "admin";
    PublicKey pubk = Encrypter.getPublicKey(this);
    username = Encrypter.encrypt(username, pubk);
```

This is my public key without `START` and `END`:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsfPDQ7tRqUw8oTPcNG3GR9OyhWnrtQXj2gmzTKdLncPIuolG1GTjYyZO25+cHSgHBlFmc20cKO0uasveZWCwuBTmMY3kVYtVblxUbHmHakLc2CRsKlCA3GAU/OAvfQfzcRUE0O1R138XcTydDGNgWKthqePJz97sEtg8nY55imVUTfRJPOeMvn1/vQQY50OTGniyoI+sh66P/0xpjrZQdIKaNADD5tQbDmrrJjoocC/GuwqBizi7rmU/p/9udNj5hCKqxL6PmejDsHss+UrhBx5t1/iem2yEBhvuOPDyvBPn/ZqAEKeAUKyf+Z5d3XQAlzJq5UjliRM2IA/K6uUBCQIDAQAB
```

My problem is that if I encrypt it using Android and then `Base64.encode` it, I get a different string than if I encrypt from PHP using the same public key

I tried encrypting the work "admin" on both sides and here's what I got:
String got from Android:

```
hF8ykDKLYVJOnHE5Uswq0+BasIRqTLnFIjvy2rLxfe/oDJ0GbhjTjoizNuSk2grKbAgkJqFN5uAFuhkqqjyxoSJlJNsQi5QRis9FDUIm1iAhjSD8olTBFky+q1pqYQsQ/Cj+9qSVTnoKpB2oJyeEk2Zx7mYegHKT/yItDtsSLa7fURaxygp1osj0Nz8pas21zXgMIyG2wKARG9IlxdBo4Vl2nj7iKwPCkHMrSeXzFjDsKOkwBzMoPuUUGSFUZ0QbL+b/Ha+Rgdb7oItzTvBfHsoL9m91j20NhqapKRYkJ2pPUhPPVDZtTzO/JPKK4ndzg32w7jKqb9zinOBcilQdGg==
```

String from PHP:

```
oh8fNeY8FwPqUkvJhFQr/2IPgdj7XEUNHjc7+KZwRGot+4DIQWtxv3N4UtzbpvkwcgI/kUjXZOz+mNSzvTEVpmZprOWBow/zlbCO7tLgH2Q131gATZdGxPEgOIVbTOWQkXL+d8x+jODnPhaXb8vUB2boQmd70ifBAq2C5mMCGPeA/gRwNquwdEG62W4zvaeXzXc6sXCXXvE6cgaWLOhZWFnLyo2ulFrkGk9XXOaWoS3HYnS35n8xHxulSEeAJOmGgEd56cSbDIlJrD9H5k6mb6PX0/eLoC7J9vdBhdM8nJVviL6NxtiOtDTCWVFb4k9il8Sksz8eascFM8yAB0KvRw==
```

For encryption in PHP I use phpseclib under Laravel 5.2 framework

Method to check credentials

```
public function creds_valid(Request $request) {
        $inputs = $request->all();

        $username = $inputs['username'];
        $password = $inputs['password'];

        $private_key = file_get_contents(storage_path() . "/phpseclib/public_key.txt");
        $rsa = new RSA();
        $rsa->loadKey($private_key);

        $username = $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($username));
        $password = $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($password));

        $credentials = [
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
//            'active' => 1
        ];

        return Auth::guard()->attempt($credentials);
    }
```

Why aren't the two algorithms output the same string on encryption and base64? I suspect some encoding issues but I can't figure them out. Tried forcing UTF-8 on both but the result is the same.. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Using this base64 library for Java:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/iharder/files/base64/2.3/

The default one from Android gives the same results so, yeah.. :/

EDIT 2:
First comment suggested checking to see if any party changes the output on concurrent executions and weirdly, yes.. The PHP one.. Why?

This is an output from `php artisan tinker`

```
base64_encode($rsa->encrypt('admin'))
=> "T3dBTadyEjvSM96lCwELNzXHNh5bEJtW6QvgdrVT0wZ2KFq8Cs+s7/+IjSrISlNC+ygF+XPhYjEUHa+FSqzgT68KftcVQYL84w8Thbiy6ElLqs7WAbLAaKk10kBqEPNtI0jItOJFXGA07SsQu6g5+OUWfEFShBPg8uSxSYPsjhvATpw6lLCRtVQYqAL1MUwwmaho/ktih5UJgpiCYdwpa0ROiPboKloO0CFOAkR+5rybSLH73p3Fxf1y46qgA3BoPenillkMW8kgv1/bFj1rpRVi2Ca3ioMQt0fOPGchoe3ikz5I6IrrAK0aYhwj3kpoQ2+doLUV+EKXs8iFkA+cjQ=="
>>> base64_encode($rsa->encrypt('admin'))
=> "XJZrhFpw1UsBEC2yKMv0PVQ/H0vvBSXEZEsjQ4vlvjgktifCGAPsac3zwarlV2+TOoNKhn7nCqWer2Gz60UyoHS0xYyNvt/i3Ogsn2ccxhpKRtrB2CEMJOzSdLoUe+4JEObdU1b6SR4ysFbFEjFvo+zWUAfT7i2vM9bdZkwcrL6S2a4bBeWk3t2l91URatggzTOBFtxUB4zHTKyo1SSuR6uqm2q/Jbakj07e64ZZQmWiKY4inDZNgaVVLE+wNq++J4aLwRhSZG4wXuPgNeGHfwgZ3bytlRJUrrNXMXExa1C8eu/js3+WiYFSXPIiTeuQaxsih+suj0abDTFjJygNMA=="
>>> base64_encode($rsa->encrypt('admin'))
=> "DVAFTjZ1Ah6mpN699/PitPj0nLNLhz4zGux9uYLQHmANR/CYEt63+z0vE2xQI9oKE/V4K5a335wvJpz+70hMy6G30cKAwerZ8PudbZgnpGRaF0YlRwzZEQ+XqV5qdQXE6kb4plVZrYrpyHAiPTmO54V+UvCp2YPbNY3Qcr+vbIrn0CZJ7lMwgE9NCGWwiIJF6G6/z4zqc+UbBG9+WUtf16BU8CXhbeU4FOSeuxYr9xbGbjAvtUZXrXpaQPYwgCuWURTWcN2fxmm5fAZuU74rPVMW5slTxTVafcIcUI0bFuMdsx3xj9VIImYhmbM0DTXT/gm66nxSy7aAvj5ckmemfA=="
>>> base64_encode($rsa->encrypt('admin'))
=> "Po8lzluh+ChWdHBxvThrn06kZ1cugTvEvV6UU8JroeM2aYwX4XH9hMSt1U+XmKkmdgxLRXwKUMsYcT7rF7I92tLW6T6fjTED1HoXXWS35okc1zhPTvXFqvMdXq7r4meLrcPmJjfsJsKnso4Ws2aIzHjQxfbPAHQNE2FD1bbOA0aD21MU8HR1qckTFosOP3O8KpxBQW3Z0aTX+k0sy0edwHfHCjQxQ9ne3oWcY+JiKCSFbyWoYxGQML0N11jA5Jik4K3jMA7cDQQzUutWUGN/ABv7OoXYKbfv/3IA8Uqu6jxSgBZjsLb4iUdFtw9QlwOsr4w2flCsPtye0vnDsjOduQ=="
>>> base64_encode($rsa->encrypt('admin'))
=> "rnkB57WUXMw87Hxc6e6MGraGryEQ+3HVwbGEexIGrs4jlqzBHZig7/ykfHzGgZGlrtYGY/FB3Mn6kfkwH1SXVAV6QPdnp0ktxbrqHJmQDDrLxsBlQGbZnSSVglV2EHn9Vm++iiygspv+IRMmOB6XOBxWMcV2AeAGa86EwTj3AKdcOeSPzrIB04G2mH695rEwLHC69KeBZ5vCuPAvVZ5AjhzsutcNEK5WLIcxcFbi1PQb7Amp3mPMpW3g0w+LkU6RkW8GGZ5gPu15PfvT/r8CCDaJbTwCLN2XPAa1R+/x0IZgSM2Tv/qOJBGdkkjGM8/lXeTGW8/oKU85bdlVqEBxdA=="
>>> base64_encode($rsa->encrypt('admin'))
=> "cX+CkQR+t9fdWMo2jHs7FdbmFzcAYkLfhNo6J0O3rAMtg8iR/KoN+RfNA6WQN4DIWMiGsN1F/ipAxiOo8K0V7x7EODgpbw2zGQBL/ueWJyD00UIA0WsXo93ubIXOJ+62dFbz7Ioc9Gtwv3q7HhtmKIh2oDxpffU1uOWzBGE8MW5cYvuWGHRqsgcKxFfiOJht+GkZUS2gdUe7/ke5YsEGLJs4PJzuk/NnPvsKEdlNHoAT+Vyzc3yW9+FtL8OpXDplACFaRS/Urulmvkd5wiy7dhCh9L1QDdgUZshkQ0In2254LFME5tVkpES0ZlD8eLZih84sioTIyeGoUj1gdkHxdw=="
>>> base64_encode($rsa->encrypt('admin'))
=> "JFVZ2dhi6vsLeiXwPDxisxRa+56fCHIM9RORhJ51hgdAr7qeb7O2o0Xx3AVJB/CfX6ZXOFwZ38sATGDpHgEbYT5Tui12IMMLTgLnQnnxyxX8+A5AfYCpAzHOr9Xr41fHdtVDTexcI+77yEakhh57SGhfUQhoTll/k73CDymLkF/DkKw21EY9DXgscffKB5giyC3bd4CiqCZ3j/aa0T70NKtjDT3H5zqrHd3dhqblYRVE7rAbKHYPz6hrv5TUX2rX45er4o53cihGOuzTlwOGDa5f0HGlepnXSvGlgmqCRMbina4LepAlker93HVD56I7rtiRRLqz9BUahkt3GSoZfA=="
>>>
```

Comment: Do any of the two ciphertexts change if you execute the encryption again (on the original plaintext)?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I edited my question(EDIT 2)

Answer (score 3):

When encryption is randomized, it provides [semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security). This property doesn't allow a passive observer of ciphertext to determine whether the plaintext behind the observed ciphertext was sent before or not. This is achieved through randomized padding ([PKCS#1 v1.5](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/can-you-explain-bleichenbachers-cca-attack-on-pkcs1-v1-5) padding type 2 or OAEP).

If you want to determine whether your code is compatible, you need to encrypt on one side and decrypt on the other.

It looks like your code should work as-is, depending on what the defaults are. You should always specify your own configuration to prevent the defaults from breaking compatibility when you switch systems.

In Java, you should always provide a fully qualified cipher string:

- `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");` or
- `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");` (OAEP is preferred nowadays)
- `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");` (OAEP is preferred nowadays)

In phpseclib, you should always change the defaults:

- `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);` or
- for OAEP with SHA-1:

  ```
  $rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
  $rsa->setHash("sha1");
  $rsa->setMGFHash("sha1");
  ```
- for OAEP with SHA-256:

  ```
  $rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
  $rsa->setHash("sha256");
  $rsa->setMGFHash("sha1");
  ```

Comment: I second OAEP. Since the asker is using phpseclib, feel free to recommend MGF1+SHA256 as well. ;)